# export to excel converting string to date

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, excel

I am pulling two fields and putting them together with a "-". When I export to excel it seems to think that the string is a date and converts it from 11-11 to 11-Nov. I can't seem to figure out how to fix this.

I am exporting a gridview into excel. This asp.net using .net 3.5 and vb.net within VS 2008.

```
    Response.Clear()

    Response.Buffer = True

    'grab filename from filename box
    'if does not exist then do default naming
    Dim filename As String
    If filenameTextBox2.Text <> "" Then
        filename = "attachment;filename=" + filenameTextBox2.Text + ".xls"
    Else
        filename = "attachment;filename=GridViewExport.xls"
    End If

    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", filename)

    Response.Charset = ""

    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"



    Dim sw As New IO.StringWriter()

    Dim hw As New HtmlTextWriter(sw)



    GridView1.AllowPaging = False

    GridView1.DataBind()


    'Change the Header Row back to white color

    GridView1.HeaderRow.Style.Add("background-color", "#FFFFFF")



    'Apply style to Individual Cells

    'GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells(0).Style.Add("background-color", "green")

    'GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells(1).Style.Add("background-color", "green")

    'GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells(2).Style.Add("background-color", "green")

    'GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells(3).Style.Add("background-color", "green")



    For i As Integer = 0 To GridView1.Rows.Count - 1

        Dim row As GridViewRow = GridView1.Rows(i)



        'Change Color back to white

        row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White



        'Apply text style to each Row

        row.Attributes.Add("class", "textmode")



        'Apply style to Individual Cells of Alternating Row

        If i Mod 2 <> 0 Then

            'row.Cells(0).Style.Add("background-color", "#C2D69B")

            'row.Cells(1).Style.Add("background-color", "#C2D69B")

            'row.Cells(2).Style.Add("background-color", "#C2D69B")

            'row.Cells(3).Style.Add("background-color", "#C2D69B")

        End If

    Next

    GridView1.RenderControl(hw)



    'style to format numbers to string

    Dim style As String = "<style>.textmode{mso-number-format:\@;}</style>"

    Response.Write(style)

    Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString())

    Response.Flush()

    Response.End()
```

Comment: Can you wrap the field value with double-quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a Single Quote (') before your content.

Comment: the ' specifies Excel Cell Format as Text.

Comment: This will work - but it's a bit hackish in my opinion. Most APIs that let you access Excel will also allow you to explicitly set the cell/column format to Text / Numeric / Date, etc.

Comment: Unless you can create a real/native Excel file, this is the correct answer. The OP is exporting the gridview to html table, which Excel will happily open (since Excel 2000, if memory serves). 

However, you cannot _"set the data type"_ without this "hack". If you want to have control over the data type, without having to use some 3rd party library, see if exporting the data as **Excel XML** will do. The caveat of course is that I don't think this will be "universal".

Text will be the "most universal" and if so, the apostrophe hack, is the only way....

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with how Excel interprets data. I would recommend you specifying the data type (via cell format) to what you need. You will also run into this problem when you want to format dates in a certain way, or don't want have leading zeros truncated off of normal data.

While using the ' at the beginning of the text will work, it also has other side effects.

Depending on how you are creating your excel file will dictate how you go about setting the cell formatting. I have had a lot of success with EPPlus.

Answer (score 0):

Your style is not working properly without quote.

Change

```
Dim style As String = "<style>.textmode{mso-number-format:\@;}</style>"
```

To

```
Dim style As String = "<style>.textmode{mso-number-format:""\@"";}</style>"
```

This works for me prefectly.